# How to push object by following its structure to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, for-loop

Here is my object structure

```
var obj = {'name':string,'place':string};
```

Here is another object

```
var arr = 
{
'a':Alpha,
'b':Australia,
'a_x':Beta,
'b_y':Canada,
'a_3':Charlie,
'b_4':China,
}
```

I want to push it to the proper object like

```
var finalArray = [
{'name':Alpha,'place':Australia},
{'name':Beta,'place':Canda},
{'name':Charlie,'place':China}
]
```

Don't know how to start with the iteration

Please help in this. Thanks in advance

Comment: What links `Alpha` to `Australia` in your second object?

Comment: I am reading it from excel. It have two rows i.e., name , place , name place like that

Comment: It doesn't tell me how two separate properties of your second object are linked.

Comment: The key name is not proper / structured.. But the the values comes one after again .. i.e., name and place

Comment: Object properties have no order. So even if you create the object like that, JavaScript is not guaranteed to loop over them in the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `Object.values` to iterate on the values; and `Array.reduce` to build up the final array going through the original data.

```js
const arr = {
  a: 'Alpha',
  b: 'Australia',
  a_x: 'Beta',
  b_y: 'Canada',
  a_3: 'Charlie',
  b_4: 'China',
};

const finalArray = Object.values(arr).reduce((tmp, x, xi) => {
  // only treat one on two
  if (!(xi % 2)) return tmp;

  return [
    ...tmp,

    {
      // Get the previous key value
      name: arr[Object.keys(arr)[xi - 1]],

      place: x,
    },
  ];
}, []);

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the values of the object and based on the index push the object in an array.

```js
const input = { 'a': 'Alpha', 'b': 'Australia', 'a_x': 'Beta', 'b_y': 'Canada', 'a_3': 'Charlie', 'b_4': 'China' },
      result = Object.values(input).reduce((r,k,i) => {
        i%2 == 0 ? r.push({name: k})  : r[Math.floor(i/2)].place = k;
        return r;
      },[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @SA__: It's not reliable, the solution is based solely on sequencing, and order of property in object are not guarantee.